# Find a match from one array to an objects property that is also an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, reduce

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to filter out if any words in one array exist in the property of an object that is also an array. The code below is an example of what I'm trying to work with and achieve.

The first array is:

```
const colors = ['red', 'green']
```

The second array of objects is as follows:

```
const articles = [
    {
      name: Peters,
      filters: ['purple', 'green']
    },
    {
      name: Frances,
      filters: ['red', 'blue']

    },
     {
      name: Carbons,
      filters: ['orange', 'blue']

     }
```

I want to be left with an array that contains the first two objects in the array since they match one of the words on the first array.
I had tried something like this:

```
{articles.filter(articles => colors.includes(articles.filters))} */}
```

I want to be left with an array of articles that DOES contain one of the words in the colors array but I can't get it to work at all.. help, please!

Answer (score 2):

```
articles.filter(
    article => article.filters.some(
        colorFilter => colors.includes(colorFilter)
    )
)
```

You need to check whether at least one of the filters is present in the colors.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Please also look into [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry, this didn't actually work for me when testing it